# DAYNAME() function SQL

Tags: sql

I want to find out the name of the week, however when I write the `DAYNAME()` function in MySql it returns the following error:

> Function not found: DAYNAME at [8:1]

I'm using the Google's big data console.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Google Big Query?

Comment: Google Big Query and the using SQL in it is MySQL. isn't it?

Answer (score 3):

Like mentionned in the documentation here : https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions

```
EXTRACT(part FROM date_expression)
```

so you want

```
EXTRACT(DAY FROM date_expression)
```

**EDIT**
You can also use `SELECT format_datetime('%A','2021-10-10')` to return the DAY NAME of the string date

Answer (score 0):

In MySql you can use Date_FORMAT)

> ```
>  SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%W');
> ```
>
> ```
> | DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%W') |
> | :----------------------- |
> | Sunday                   |
> ```

> ```
> SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%a');
> ```
>
> ```
> | DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%a') |
> | :----------------------- |
> | Sun                      |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d06dde78f0f28faa35771e8dc35c4b79)*